# How to read NFC tags Simultaneously?

Tags: nfc, communication, rfid

I look for solution for problem in my  project.

The idea of the project is to create a smart library which help us to know where every book located in every period of time.

**Picture :**
[image]

The idea is to make a scanner which pass over the shelf and scans the books every 30 minutes.

I thought to implement that project with NFC tags and NFC scanner, but i found that there is **limitions of distance** between one tag to another.

**Another problem** is that i want to read radius of tags and not tag after tag (like QR code for example) becouse i dont know in which position the book will be on the shelf.

**Picture of the problem :**
[image]

***The questions are***

**1.** If the limit of NFC tags distance is more or less milimeters
**2.** If there is another cheap solution for reading some objects which are located in distance of 5-10 centimeter from some scanner

Comment: Interesting question, however it's offtopic to SO. Please try ask your question [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/). And good luck with your project

Comment: thanks, I will check it.